# Displaying JSON content

Tags: javascript, json

This should be pretty simple, I'm just pretty new to this. All I want to know how to do is how to display the following information from this file: http://worldoftanks.com/community/accounts/1003576349/api/1.8/?source_token=WG-WoT_Assistant-1.3.2

I want to display (for example purposes) the following using javascript:

- -status
- -vehicles -> spotted
- -summary -> wins
- -data -> defender

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just deal with json as normal javascript object and access its properties/ arrays as you do for any other object. you can get the values that you are looking for like this. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JsvWm/)

```
var json={...yourjson...};
alert('status ' + json.status);
alert('Spotted ' + json.data.vehicles[0].spotted);
alert('Wins ' + json.data.summary.wins);
alert('defender ' + json.data.achievements.defender);
```

For further dwelling look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript) Post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to parse Json

```
var output=jQuery.parseJSON(YOUR_JSON);
```

variable output will give you Object, From there you can easily extract data

```
document.write(output.query);
```